# AC internal unit blow fan - cleaning mold

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cleaning

My internal unit has mold building up on the blower (see schematic below).

I'm not sure if it's mold or if it's dust, but I'm pretty sure it needs to be cleaned.

The only easy way to reach it is from the outtake (blue arrow in schematic) 
but it's very hard to give it a proper cleaning from there. The openings are small and it's hard to remove all of the dirt/mold from the fans.

I used a pressure washer once, and it did a pretty good job, but I'm afraid this is not the optimal way to clean the unit - both because the water can possibly damage the unit (electricity and water) and the fact that it "blows" the dirt/mold instead of properly removing it from the unit (i.e, mold parts will fly all over the evaporator)

What's a good way to clean the blower, WITHOUT disassembling the whole unit (which is a pain)?

[image]

Comment: What does the instruction manual say to do?

Comment: Sadly - pretty much nothing about this issue. This is not the first time I'm having mold issues with split ACs...